# I accidentally corrupted external dependencies in VS2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I was trying to format my code in Visual Studio with AStyle extension and I edited accidentally the header TIHelp32.h. Now it doesn't works and I want it back by default.

How can I do this, I tried to repair the Visual Studio Cummunity 2017 installation but the header still being broken.

Comment: You could remove the affected Windows SDK in the VS 2017 Installer, apply the changes and add it again afterwards (including the things that were uninstalled cause they depend on the SDK).

Comment: Go to your back up. That's a joke of course.

Comment: if they still use CAB's for installer you can try find file there, it's openable trough several archive managers.. also , wouldn't SDK be a protected folder that can be restored via `sfc` command?